# C10K for the modern world

Tags: networking

Answering [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014856/how-to-know-when-bytes-are-to-send-recv-from-client-server-c/5016525) question made me wonder: is there nice modern version of the [famous C10K page](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html)? 5 years passed from the time it was updated and I'm sure there're advances in the field.
Perhaps current version would be called something like C1M problem? ;)

Comment: Maybe take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129608/is-there-any-modern-review-of-solutions-to-the-10000-client-sec-problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the modern world of things like distributed load-balancers and content distribution networks, I'm not sure that a single system having to be able to handle such a large number of concurrent connections is as big a deal.  These days scalability is more about scaling **out** to distribute than scaling **up** to beef up your capabilities.

Comment: I think it is nice to think that a single server can handle 10K connections, as a starting point.  Then you can slow down from there ... adding more servers introduces some overhead you might want to put off as long as possible (session synchronization, load balancing) ...

Answer (score 2):

There's [a million user comet application](http://www.metabrew.com/article/a-million-user-comet-application-with-mochiweb-part-3) , though it investigates Erlang(+ OS tuning)